# Xamarin Forms ListView Inside CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a collection view whose source is an IObservable(Object1) inside of each Object1 is a List(Object2).
I would like to show each Object2 that is related to its Object1.

I have tried to place a ListView inside of a collectionView

I am getting the error System.InvalidOperationException LoadTemplate should not be null

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Object1Collection}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.65*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                
                                <Label TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Response}"></Label>

                                <Label TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Restriction: "></Label>
                                
                                <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Object2List }">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <!--
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding Statistic}"></Label>
                                                <Label TextColor="Black" Text=" : "></Label>
                                                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Amount}"></Label>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            -->
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Comment: nesting List/Collections is generally not a good idea

Comment: What is the solution to this if I shouldn't nest?

Comment: use Grouping, or redesign your UI to eliminate the nesting

Comment: Grouping ok I shall google that, and how would I change my UI to eliminate that?

Comment: I don't know.  Talk to whoever generates your UX or business requirements.  Your description of the problem is really vague so it's impossible to give specific suggestions.

Comment: My issue is with the UI though, I need each item in the collection view to display alongside it or in it each item in the listview. The listview though is a list property inside of the object in the collection view. CollectionView[{object1 [object2]}, {object1 [object2]}}. It is a uni project so I can kinda have it how I want if that makes sense

Comment: if it's a school project and you don't care about performance or usability, then go ahead and nest away

Comment: Problem is, it's not working and I am getting a System.InvalidOperationException LoadTemplate should not be null

Comment: nowhere in your question did you mention anything about an exception or error.  If you want help solving a specific problem, you have to ask a question about **that specific problem** and provide the necessary detail, not a vague general question about it.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought I had added it but I hadn't sorry

Comment: I'd probably start by fixing the empty DataTemplate

Comment: Debugging 101: **isolate** the problem. Basic technique is to find the **minimum code** that has the problem. Remove everything. Add bits of code, in as small a chunk as possible. Leave out anything that doesn't break it. Ideally, there will be a single line of code that when added, takes a working program (that doesn't do what you want of course), and breaks it. That will tell you a lot about what is wrong - and will turn your "My Code Doesn't Work" question into a very specific question, that someone likely will immediately spot the solution to. Or even better, you might see it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CollectionView Grouping`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Xaml:

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Object1Collection}" IsGrouped="True">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Label Text="{Binding Response}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollView>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Statistic}"/>
                            <Label TextColor="Black" Text=" : "></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        
    </CollectionView>
```

Model:

```
 public class Object1Model : List<Object2Model>
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public Object1Model(string response, List<Object2Model> Object2List) : base(Object2List)
    {
        Response = response;
    }
}

public class Object2Model
{
    public string Statistic { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Code behind:

```
  public ObservableCollection<Object1Model> Object1Collection { get; set; }
    public Page23()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Object1Collection = new ObservableCollection<Object1Model>();
        Object1Collection.Add(new Object1Model("Object1A", new List<Object2Model>
        {
            new Object2Model(){ Statistic="Object2Statistic1A", Amount="Object2Amount1A"},
            new Object2Model(){ Statistic="Object2Statistic1A", Amount="Object2Amount1A"},
        }));
        Object1Collection.Add(new Object1Model("Object1B", new List<Object2Model>
        {
            new Object2Model(){ Statistic="Object2Statistic1B", Amount="Object2Amount1B"},
            new Object2Model(){ Statistic="Object2Statistic1B", Amount="Object2Amount1B"},
        })); 
        Object1Collection.Add(new Object1Model("Object1C", new List<Object2Model>
        {
            new Object2Model(){ Statistic="Object2Statistic1C", Amount="Object2Amount1C"},
            new Object2Model(){ Statistic="Object2Statistic1C", Amount="Object2Amount1C"},
        }));

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It works you my friend are a life saver! Is it possible to get this to work if I had both a List(Object2) and a List(Object3)?

Comment: What is your object3? Is it related to object2 which is the level2 ( object is level1, object2 is level2 and object 3 is level3)?

Comment: object3 is the exact same as object2 it's at the same level and it too a list of objects of the same model type

Answer (score 0):

Add `ViewCell` under `DataTemplate` of ListView.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Object2List }">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding Statistic}"></Label>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text=" : "></Label>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Amount}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Fix those two exceptions:

1. No viewcell error:
   `'Specified cast is not valid.'`
2. Comment out the StackLayout error:
   `'LoadTemplate should not be null'`